# Memory management error. Computer fails to power on

Tags: windows-10, power, memory-management

Just now my PC (which runs windows 10 ) experienced a memory management error where it ran (headfirst) into a BSOD. and restarted after the 'we will restart when we are done collecting info' screen.

During the restart I heard a dub sound (the kind of one your heart makes) and a few seconds later my computer was powered off.

I tried restarting to check whether there was any (temporary) issue with the RAM and whatnot however my PC refused to power on itself (no display; no beeps; nothing).

I am worried as to:

- have I fried my PC (I can't smell anything funny so probably not but still)
- what can I do to get around this

**Edit 1:** As suggested by @Twisty I tried to restart my PC after some time it did power on momentarily (for like 1-2 seconds) before again powering off

Comment: This particular BSOD is mostly about software errors (as in “bad programming”). Like almost any error it could theoretically also be caused by hardware. So it’s very unlikely to be related to your problems. // What exactly produced your heartbeat sound? The speaker system? Or something inside your PC.

Comment: I don't know. Since the computer fails to power on despite being plugged in I presume it's a hardware fault. Also the speaker plug is kind of loose but does not produce such sounds unless there happens to be another load on the circuit (which in my case is a washing machine)

Comment: Try leaving the PC unplugged for several minutes then start it again. Also try removing all but one RAM module. Try starting with each RAM module individually.

Comment: if you can boot the PC again, share the dmp files from C:\windows\minidump, so that I can analyze them. in the meantime, do a RAM test with memtest86+.

Comment: @Twisty. I have only one RAM modules. In this case what can I do

Comment: In that case the best you could do would be get your hands on another compatible RAM module and try it instead of yours.